# AppStore and alternatives for the following app

Tags: iphone, app-store

I got an offer to develop a simple iPhone app that would call a web service with user's credentials. An user would get the list of files that can be downloaded (.pdfs) and could then download the wanted file. Simple enough...

Now, I've had bad experience with publishing on AppStore. Basically, they refused one app because according to them our RSS reader for a online newspaper wasn't in accordance with their guidelines. They said that the application was a simple web aggregator which I won't argue now. Not now :)

So, back to the new app problem :)
**I would like to know what are the options for distributing the new app**. The client has a web page and wants to give it's visitor this app to get that data from their phones too.
Technically, the app doesn't have to be a native app. It can be a phoneGap solution too since it's quite simple regarding the functionality. Sincerely, I am afraid that there is no way that Apple will allow this app to be uploaded to their store being native, phoneGap...

P.S.
I would also like to know is there a way to distribute an "internal" (not publicly available) iPhone app? For example, a company needs an internal tool for their 500 employees, but can't afford to go through the process of conecting each device and compiling the app for each device individually...

Comment: I am sorry if I insulted you with my question and I don't see the constructiveness of your answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to sell customized apps to companies, you should consider the **B2B program**.

if you are in an enterprise that wants to deploy apps inside your company, the **Enterprise Developer Program** is a good choice.

Answer (score 1):

For internal:

100 test devices.

alot of iphones with the distribution profile after the 100 devices

with the enterprise:

https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/